# PHP How to replace spacific array value to another array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this array results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subscription_id] => 67
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1036
            [title] => Rotchild 50, Tel Aviv, Israel
            [subscription_plan_id] => 13
            [transactionID] => VHHDLY2P5CC7V5K34UA5SUFWVM
            [transactionDisplayID] => 441486
            [paid_with] => Visa
            [active] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-02-11 09:22:08
            [end_date] => 2015-03-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:29:33
            [s_subscription_id] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subscription_id] => 66
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1036
            [title] => Rotchild 50, Tel Aviv, Israel
            [subscription_plan_id] => 2
            [transactionID] => VHHDLY2P5CC7V5K34UA5SUFWVM
            [transactionDisplayID] => 441486
            [paid_with] => Visa
            [active] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-02-11 09:22:07
            [end_date] => 2015-03-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:26:50
            [s_subscription_id] => 69
        )

)
```

Now How to replace `end_date` key value to `start_date` key value with incrementing with 1 day like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subscription_id] => 67
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1036
            [title] => Rotchild 50, Tel Aviv, Israel
            [subscription_plan_id] => 13
            [transactionID] => VHHDLY2P5CC7V5K34UA5SUFWVM
            [transactionDisplayID] => 441486
            [paid_with] => Visa
            [active] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-03-13
            [end_date] => 2015-03-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:29:33
            [s_subscription_id] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subscription_id] => 66
            [user_id] => 156
            [property_id] => 1036
            [title] => Rotchild 50, Tel Aviv, Israel
            [subscription_plan_id] => 2
            [transactionID] => VHHDLY2P5CC7V5K34UA5SUFWVM
            [transactionDisplayID] => 441486
            [paid_with] => Visa
            [active] => 1
            [start_date] => 2015-03-13
            [end_date] => 2015-03-12
            [s_start_date] => 2015-02-12 09:26:50
            [s_subscription_id] => 69
        )

)
```

Any Idea how to replace spacific array value to another?

Comment: Does this array originate with a database query? If so, (assuming MySQL) it would be easier to query the `start_date` value with a MySQL date function like `end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY` than to post-process the date in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at nested, associative arrays. If you know the indexes and keys then it's pretty easy:

```
$endDate = str_replace('-', '/', your_array[0]['end_date']);
your_array[0]['start_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate.'+1 days'));

$endDate = str_replace('-', '/', your_array[1]['end_date']);
your_array[1]['start_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate.'+1 days'));
```

For more details about manipulating date/time you should review the manual for the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and date functions.

Comment: Hi I have tried your logic and implement with loop and its wordking great for me. :)